# "100^-(1+2*1:3)"

Tags: r

```
options(digits = 4, scipen = 0)
"100^-(1+2*1:3)"=1e-06 1e-10 1e-14
```

I don't know how it works.
Why it could be 1e-06?

Comment: Are you aware of what `1+2*1:3` outputs?

Comment: The result of `"100^-(1+2*1:3)"` is only the character vector (with only one element): `"100^-(1+2*1:3)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained working of your expression

```
100^-(1+2*1:3)

(10^2)^-(1+2(1 2 3))

(10^2)^-(1+(2 4 6))

(10^2)^-(3 5 7)

(10^-6 10^-10 10^-14)
```